# (FLUTTER) checkbox setState again when turn off/on the keyboard?

Tags: flutter

I am still new to Flutter, I'm learning and doing a project for myself and creating a checkbox list, everything is good until I detect an annoying little bug. Here is my code:

[Constructor of checkbox] https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Vzd.png

```dart
class CheckboxModal {
  String? title;
  bool value;
  CheckboxModal({this.title, this.value = false});
}
```

[Create a checkbox widget] https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZkgD.png

```dart
Widget buildingSingleCheckbox(CheckboxModal select) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, _setState) {
      return CheckboxListTile(
        value: select.value,
        title: Text(select.title as String),
        onChanged: (value) => _setState(() {
          select.value = value!;
        }),
      );
    });
```

[Create a list of checkboxes based on data of an API] https://i.stack.imgur.com/PniOQ.png

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: fetchCategories(),
  builder: ((context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.data == null) {
   return Container();
 } else {
   return ListView.builder(
   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) => 
Container(
  child: buildingSingleCheckbox(
      CheckboxModal(title: snapshot.data[index].type)),
  ),
  );
 }
 })),
```

[This is the text field where I trigger to turn on/off a keyboard] https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8fP2.png

```
TextField(
  controller: searchController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
  hintText: 'Keywords',
  suffixIcon: IconButton(
  onPressed: searchController.clear,
  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
    ),
 ),
 ),
```

The case is when I checked any Checkboxes, I click on a text field a keyboard pop-up all checkboxes that have been checked (value is true) are unchecked (value is false). And the same, the keyboard was still there, I checked any Checkboxes, and clicked the turn back button (of the phone, the bottom toolbar) to turn off the keyboard and the value of the checkboxes changed from true to false, but if the values is already false, it's not changed.

Comment: Please add the code to your question, don't use images!

Comment: I'm sorry, first time posting on StackOverflow :) I just updated the code, I thought the website can automatically render the image link

Comment: post a runnable code sample for us to help. not an image

Comment: I run the code by my phone or emulator, no error on console and nothing print out on console, just a wrong logic elsewhere of the code. unfortunately, I have record the bug but is bad that I can't upload the video here

Answer (score 0):

Problem Statement (Some pointers to help you).

1. Keyboard on/off triggers widget rebuild
2. You hardcoded the value to be false when you called the sub widget (buildingSingleCheckbox)
3. Everytime you click check/uncheck. the value within the checkbox widget (CheckboxListTile) is being refreshed only but not the parent.
4. The moment you call keyboard toggle, the parent widget is being initialized/rebuilt triggering to rebuild the widget with original values (i.e. false).
5. More information: Technically snapshot is a final so no updates happen back to this object

Solution:

1. Declare a list / map in the parent widget
2. Set the value of your data to this list / map
3. Pass the value from this list /map to the sub widget (buildingSingleCheckbox)
4. In your sub widget when change, update the parent list / map

Hope this helps